# how to concat jq paths in each array

Tags: json, jq

Here is the json paths which ends with 'headline' I have got:

```
jq -c 'paths | select(.[-1] == "headline")' news.json

["data","legacyCollection","collectionsPage","stream","edges",0,"node","headline"]
["data","legacyCollection","collectionsPage","stream","edges",1,"node","headline"]
["data","legacyCollection","collectionsPage","stream","edges",2,"node","headline"]
```

How can I **get one step further** which is concat all elements in a single path.
to turn my output from:

```
["data","legacyCollection","collectionsPage","stream","edges",2,"node","headline"]
```

to

```
'.data.legacyCollection.collectionsPage.stream.edges[2].node'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the last element, prepend a dot to `strings`, wrap `numbers` in brackets, and `join` the array:

```sh
.[:-1] | map(strings = ".\(.)" | numbers = "[\(.)]") | join("")
```

```json
".data.legacyCollection.collectionsPage.stream.edges[0].node"
".data.legacyCollection.collectionsPage.stream.edges[1].node"
".data.legacyCollection.collectionsPage.stream.edges[2].node"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/4TyeEF29rb)

Comment: one mroe question :it works with command below as well : map(strings = ".\(.)" | numbers = "[\(.)]") | join("")  . The difference is I removed '|' after 'strings' and 'numbers' , any reasons of having them in your commands ? @pmf

Comment: @Jia `|=` is used to "update" the LHS, which means that the context `.` for the RHS filters is being set to the old value. But as `strings` and `numbers` are just shorthand for (a selection of) the context anyway, they don't serve any purpose here. Well spotted!